# How to convert from hibernate SQLQuery result to JSON

Tags: java, hibernate, javabeans, json

I have a problem, I'm trying to convert an SQLQuery object result (from Hibernate) to a JSON.

```
   SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM table");
   List<javaBean> list = q.list();
```

Afterward I would like to convert that into a pretty JSON that has all the attribute name.

What's a good strategy?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google-gson: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/, it's quite good for converting  Java beans to json:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples

Answer (score 0):

You could hook up a JAX-RS service to return your bean as JSON. Take a look at Jersey.